# JQuery Import Error?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code perfectly working in this [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/DDV98/59/) @ http://jsfiddle.net/DDV98/59/ but when i try to run it on localhost by inserting these codes as shown below using Sublime, it does not work as shown in JSFiddle. May i know what did it went wrong?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pusat Pengajian </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/layout1.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#pensyarah-tab .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        $('#pensyarah-tab ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Dr X</h1>
  <div id="content-pensyarah"> 

    <img class="imgl" src="../pic/X.png" style="width: 250px; height: 300px; float: left;">
  </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

<div id="pensyarah-tab">
  <div id="column">
  <div class="subnav">
  <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab0">Biodata</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Akademic</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Bidang Penyelidikan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Kepakaran</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Penerbitan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">Pengajaran</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab6">Penyeliaan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab7">Perundingan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab8">Pentadbiran</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>

<div class="tabcontainer">
          <!-- Tab0 -->
        <div id="tab0" class="tab active clear">
        <table class="no-border fl_left">
        <tr>
          <td>Nama</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Dr. Antimage</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Akademik</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>PhD ( - ), BSc ( - )</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jawatan</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Director</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bidang Kajian</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Applied Statistics</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Emel</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>helpme@mh.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ext</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>01344</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bilik</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>D2-2-23</td>
        </tr>

      </table>    
      </div>         
      <!-- Tab0 -->

    <!-- Tab1 -->
      <div id="tab1" class="tab clear">
        <h1>Dr Ancient Appiration</h1>

        <div id="content-pensyarah"> 

            <table class="no-border fl_left">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Kelayakan Akademik</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>BSc ( Industrial Mathematics ) - </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>PhD ( Mathematics ) -</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>           
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Tab1 -->

      <!-- Tab2 -->
          <div id="tab2" class="tab clear">
        <h1>Dr Axe</h1>

        <div id="content-pensyarah"> 

            <table class="no-border fl_left">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Kelayakan Akademik</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>BSc ( Industrial Mathematics )0- </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>PhD ( Mathematics ) -0</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>           
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Tab2 -->

    <!-- Tab3 -->
          <div id="tab3" class="tab clear">
        <h1>Dr GG</h1>

        <div id="content-pensyarah"> 

            <table class="no-border fl_left">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Kelayakan Akademik</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>BSc ( Industrial Mathematics ) -- </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>PhD ( Mathematics ) --</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>           
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Tab3 -->
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 /* ----------------------------------------------Clear-------------------------------------*/
.clear:after{content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; line-      height:0;}
.clear{display:inline-block;}
html[xmlns] .clear{display:block;}
* html .clear{height:1%;}

/* ----------------------------------------------Column--------------------------------  -----*/

#column{
display:block;
float:right;
width:300px;
}

#column .holder, #column #featured{
display:block;
width:300px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

#column .holder h2.title{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:65px;
margin:0;
padding:15px 0 0 0;
font-size:20px;
line-height:normal;
border-bottom:1px dotted #999999;
}

#column .holder h2.title img{
float:left;
margin:-15px 8px 0 0;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #999999;
}

#column div.imgholder{
display:block;
width:290px;
margin:0 0 10px 0;
padding:4px;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#column .holder p.readmore{
display:block;
width:100%;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:right;
line-height:normal;
}

/* Featured Block */

#column #featured ul, #column #featured h2, #column #featured p{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
color:#666666;
background-color:#F7F7F7;
}

#column #featured a{
color:#B86365;
background-color:#F7F7F7;
}

#column #featured li{
display:block;
width:250px;
margin:0;
padding:20px 25px;
color:#666666;
background-color:#F7F7F7;
}

#column #featured li p.imgholder{
display:block;
width:240px;
height:90px;
margin:20px 0 15px 0;
padding:4px;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#column #featured li h2{
margin:0;
padding:0 0 8px 0;
font-weight:normal;
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
line-height:normal;
border-bottom:1px dotted #999999;
}

#container #column .readmore a{
display:block;
width:100%;
margin-top:15px;
height:auto;
padding-left:0;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:right;
line-height:normal;
background:none;
}

#column .latestnews{
display:block;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

#column .latestnews li{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:99px;
margin:0 0 11px 0;
padding:0 0 21px 0;
border-bottom:1px dotted #C7C5C8;
overflow:hidden;
}

#column .latestnews li.last{
margin-bottom:0;
}

#column .latestnews p{
display:inline;
}

#column .latestnews img{
float:left;
margin:0 10px 0 0;
padding:4px;
border:1px solid #C7C5C8;
clear:left;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------Column Navigation-------------------------------------*/
#column{
width: 20%;
}

#column .subnav{display:block; width:180px; padding:25px; background-color:#F1F1F1; margin-bottom:30px;}

#column .subnav h2{
margin:0 0 20px 0;
padding:0 0 14px 0;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:normal;
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color:#666666;
background-color:#F7F7F7;
line-height:normal;
border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;
}

#column .subnav ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

#column .subnav li{
margin:0 0 3px 0;
padding:0;
}

#column .subnav ul ul, #column .subnav ul ul ul, #column .subnav ul ul ul ul, #column .subnav ul ul ul ul ul{border-top:none; padding-top:0;}

#column .subnav a{
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:5px 10px 5px 20px;
color:#666666;
background:url("../images/pink_file.gif") no-repeat 10px center #F1F1F1;
text-decoration:none;
border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;
}

#column .subnav a:hover{color:#B86365; background-color:#F7F7F7;}

#column .subnav ul ul a, #column .subnav ul ul ul a, #column .subnav ul ul ul ul a,     #column .subnav ul ul ul ul ul a{background:url("../images/black_file.gif") no-repeat #F7F7F7;}
#column .subnav ul ul a{padding-left:40px; background-position:30px center;}
#column .subnav ul ul ul a{padding-left:50px; background-position:40px center;}
#column .subnav ul ul ul ul a{padding-left:60px; background-position:50px center;}
#column .subnav ul ul ul ul ul a{padding-left:70px; background-position:60px center;}

/* ------Pensyarah Part only-----*/
#content-pensyarah{
display:block;
float:left;
width:60%;
}
/* ------Pensyarah Part only-----*/


/*----- Tabs -----*/
#pensyarah-tab {
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

/*----- Tab Links -----*/
/* Clearfix */
#pensyarah-tab .tab-links:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:'';
}

#pensyarah-tab .tab-links li {
    margin:0px 5px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}

    .tab-links a {
        padding:9px 15px;
        display:inline-block;
        border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
        background:#7FB5DA;
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:600;
        color:#4c4c4c;
        transition:all linear 0.15s;
    }

    .tab-links a:hover {
        background:#a7cce5;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

.tab-links li.active a, li.active a:hover {
    background:#fff;
    color:#4c4c4c;
}

/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
#pensyarah-tab .tabcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  background:#FAFAFA;
}

#pensyarah-tab .tabcontainer .tab {
  display:none;
}

#pensyarah-tab .tabcontainer .active {
  display:block;
}
```

p/s: Please note that the codes are the same as in JSFiddle, just some changes to change to inline import for JQuery.

Comment: include `jQuery Library` above your script

Comment: where is your jquery ?

Comment: You should learn how to debug your web page

Comment: I am new to Jquery. Sry about that

Answer (score 0):

jQuery isn't included in your code, so the errors you're seeing will be about things like `$` being undefined. jQuery is however included in your JSFiddle demo (through the options in the left sidebar). You need to include it in your code. You can either download it ([from jQuery's own website](http://jquery.com/download/)) and host it locally, including it using:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can instead use a CDN like [Google's](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) by including:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you're using the above snippet locally you'll need to change `"//...` to `"http://...`.

*Note that I'm using jQuery 1.10.1 here as that is what your JSFiddle demo uses.*

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to add Jquery in your code like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

With this code you not need to download jquery to your proyect.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

I have included jQuery code, which you have not included.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> Pusat Pengajian </title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .clear:after{content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; line-height:0;}
.clear{display:inline-block;}
html[xmlns] .clear{display:block;}
* html .clear{height:1%;}

/* ----------------------------------------------Column-------------------------------------*/

#column{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    }

#column .holder, #column #featured{
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    }

#column .holder h2.title{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:65px;
    margin:0;
    padding:15px 0 0 0;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:normal;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #999999;
    }

#column .holder h2.title img{
    float:left;
    margin:-15px 8px 0 0;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #999999;
    }

#column div.imgholder{
    display:block;
    width:290px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:4px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    }

#column .holder p.readmore{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:right;
    line-height:normal;
    }

/* Featured Block */

#column #featured ul, #column #featured h2, #column #featured p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    color:#666666;
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    }

#column #featured a{
    color:#B86365;
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    }

#column #featured li{
    display:block;
    width:250px;
    margin:0;
    padding:20px 25px;
    color:#666666;
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    }

#column #featured li p.imgholder{
    display:block;
    width:240px;
    height:90px;
    margin:20px 0 15px 0;
    padding:4px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    }

#column #featured li h2{
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 8px 0;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    line-height:normal;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #999999;
    }

#container #column .readmore a{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:15px;
    height:auto;
    padding-left:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:right;
    line-height:normal;
    background:none;
    }

#column .latestnews{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    }

#column .latestnews li{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:99px;
    margin:0 0 11px 0;
    padding:0 0 21px 0;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #C7C5C8;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

#column .latestnews li.last{
    margin-bottom:0;
    }

#column .latestnews p{
    display:inline;
    }

#column .latestnews img{
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    padding:4px;
    border:1px solid #C7C5C8;
    clear:left;
    }

/* ----------------------------------------------Column Navigation-------------------------------------*/
#column{
    width: 20%;
}

#column .subnav{display:block; width:180px; padding:25px; background-color:#F1F1F1; margin-bottom:30px;}

#column .subnav h2{
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
    padding:0 0 14px 0;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#666666;
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    line-height:normal;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;
    }

#column .subnav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    }

#column .subnav li{
    margin:0 0 3px 0;
    padding:0;
    }

#column .subnav ul ul, #column .subnav ul ul ul, #column .subnav ul ul ul ul, #column .subnav ul ul ul ul ul{border-top:none; padding-top:0;}

#column .subnav a{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 20px;
    color:#666666;
    background:url("../images/pink_file.gif") no-repeat 10px center #F1F1F1;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;
    }

#column .subnav a:hover{color:#B86365; background-color:#F7F7F7;}

#column .subnav ul ul a, #column .subnav ul ul ul a, #column .subnav ul ul ul ul a, #column .subnav ul ul ul ul ul a{background:url("../images/black_file.gif") no-repeat #F7F7F7;}
#column .subnav ul ul a{padding-left:40px; background-position:30px center;}
#column .subnav ul ul ul a{padding-left:50px; background-position:40px center;}
#column .subnav ul ul ul ul a{padding-left:60px; background-position:50px center;}
#column .subnav ul ul ul ul ul a{padding-left:70px; background-position:60px center;}

/* ------Pensyarah Part only-----*/
#content-pensyarah{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    }
/* ------Pensyarah Part only-----*/


/*----- Tabs -----*/
#pensyarah-tab {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

    /*----- Tab Links -----*/
    /* Clearfix */
#pensyarah-tab .tab-links:after {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        content:'';
    }

#pensyarah-tab .tab-links li {
        margin:0px 5px;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
    }

        .tab-links a {
            padding:9px 15px;
            display:inline-block;
            border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
            background:#7FB5DA;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:600;
            color:#4c4c4c;
            transition:all linear 0.15s;
        }

        .tab-links a:hover {
            background:#a7cce5;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

    .tab-links li.active a, li.active a:hover {
        background:#fff;
        color:#4c4c4c;
    }

    /*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
#pensyarah-tab .tabcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    background:#FAFAFA;
}

#pensyarah-tab .tabcontainer .tab {
    display:none;
}

#pensyarah-tab .tabcontainer .active {
    display:block;
}

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pensyarah-tab .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        $('#pensyarah-tab ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
   <h1>Dr X</h1>
      <div id="content-pensyarah"> 

        <img class="imgl" src="../pic/X.png" style="width: 250px; height: 300px; float: left;">
      </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

<div id="pensyarah-tab">
    <div id="column">
    <div class="subnav">
    <ul class="tab-links">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab0">Biodata</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab1">Akademic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Bidang Penyelidikan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Kepakaran</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab4">Penerbitan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab5">Pengajaran</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab6">Penyeliaan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab7">Perundingan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab8">Pentadbiran</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tabcontainer">
              <!-- Tab0 -->
            <div id="tab0" class="tab active clear">
            <table class="no-border fl_left">
            <tr>
              <td>Nama</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>Dr. Antimage</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Akademik</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>PhD ( - ), BSc ( - )</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Jawatan</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>Director</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Bidang Kajian</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>Applied Statistics</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Emel</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>helpme@mh.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ext</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>01344</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Bilik</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>D2-2-23</td>
            </tr>

          </table>    
          </div>         
          <!-- Tab0 -->

        <!-- Tab1 -->
          <div id="tab1" class="tab clear">
            <h1>Dr Ancient Appiration</h1>

            <div id="content-pensyarah"> 

                <table class="no-border fl_left">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Kelayakan Akademik</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>BSc ( Industrial Mathematics ) - </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>PhD ( Mathematics ) -</td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>           
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Tab1 -->

          <!-- Tab2 -->
              <div id="tab2" class="tab clear">
            <h1>Dr Axe</h1>

            <div id="content-pensyarah"> 

                <table class="no-border fl_left">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Kelayakan Akademik</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>BSc ( Industrial Mathematics )0- </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>PhD ( Mathematics ) -0</td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>           
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Tab2 -->

        <!-- Tab3 -->
              <div id="tab3" class="tab clear">
            <h1>Dr GG</h1>

            <div id="content-pensyarah"> 

                <table class="no-border fl_left">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Kelayakan Akademik</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>BSc ( Industrial Mathematics ) -- </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>PhD ( Mathematics ) --</td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>           
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Tab3 -->
    </div>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I have just included `jquery` which was not in OP's question